# "'ThemeableBrowserOptions' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here", in app.module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

```
import { ThemeableBrowser, ThemeableBrowserOptions, ThemeableBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/themeable-browser';

constructor(  private themeableBrowser: ThemeableBrowser)
```

“'ThemeableBrowserOptions' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here”, in app.module

Comment: Please also quote the part where that type is used.

Comment: add ngx at end of line
    import { ThemeableBrowser, ThemeableBrowserOptions, ThemeableBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/themeable-browser/ngx';